# hook_form_alter() on a view exposed filter form

Tags: views, 8, forms

I am trying to add a disable attribute in a field using the hook_form_id_alter function.  I created a module and built the function

```
function disableIncentiveform_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-drive-clean-incentive-search-page-1'){
    $form['field_new_used']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
  }
}
```

However, this does not add an attribute to the form.

I know there used to be a hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter function in D7 but I can't find anything specific for D8.  Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: Have you also tried it with just `hook_form_alter`?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I thought module names have to be all lower case: disable`i`ncentiveform_form_views_exposed_form_alter()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $view_ids = ['YOUR_VIEW_ID'];
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && in_array($form_state->get('view')->id(), $view_ids)) {
    $form['field_new_used']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
  }
}
```